# Interactive Scatter Plot with filter bars in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to built a interactive scatter plot in python where i have a box, where i can click on another category and the plot is chaning. Right now I have this scatter plot for only one category (e.g. T-Shirts), based on the follinwg code:

```
METPrint = METView

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors = {'y':'red', 'n':'black'}

METPrint = METPrint[METPrint['Gender']=='Women']
METPrint = METPrint[METPrint['Class']=='T-Shirts']

ax.scatter(METPrint['EOH'], METPrint['SellOff'], c=METPrint['MarkdownFlag'].apply(lambda x: colors[x]))

plt.show()
```

Right now my rawdata looks like this:

```
Gender  Class SellOff   EOH MarkdownFlag
```

I want to have a filter i can click for the Class instead of writing 'T-Shirts' in the code above, can somehelp me out?

Thanks